# Unable to unsort the table by clicking the column - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

As I shifted from Laravel Livewire to Laravel Vue, I am unable to recreate the logic required for sorting in Vue. I am successfully able to sort the table by clicking the table header. Now, what I need here is, as when the `sortDirection` is 'desc', the click after that should unsort the column just like in the Livewire Component example shown below. Please help me achieve this in vue.

User Index Vue Component - Current Behavior

[image]

User Index Livewire Component - Required Behavior

[image]

User Index Vue Component - Script

```
<script>
    export default {
        props : ['users'],
        data() {
            return {
                sortField: '',
                sortDirection: 'asc'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sortBy: function(column) {
                if (column === this.sortField) {
                    this.sortDirection = this.sortDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
                } else this.sortDirection = 'asc';
                this.sortField = column;
            }
        },
        computed:{
            sortedUsers: function() {
                return this.users.sort((a, b) => {
                    let modifier = 1;
                    if (this.sortDirection === 'desc') modifier = -1;
                    if (a[this.sortField] < b[this.sortField]) return -1 * modifier; 
                    if (a[this.sortField] > b[this.sortField]) return 1 * modifier;
                    return 0;
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

User Index Vue Component - Template

```
<template #head>
    <data-table-heading sortable :direction="sortField === 'id' ? sortDirection : null" @click="sortBy('id')" class="pr-0">ID</data-table-heading>
    <data-table-heading sortable :direction="sortField === 'name' ? sortDirection : null" @click="sortBy('name')">Name</data-table-heading>
    <data-table-heading sortable :direction="sortField === 'email' ? sortDirection : null" @click="sortBy('email')" class="w-screen">Email</data-table-heading>
    <data-table-heading sortable :direction="sortField === 'role' ? sortDirection : null" @click="sortBy('role')">Role</data-table-heading>
    <data-table-heading sortable :direction="sortField === 'created_at' ? sortDirection : null" @click="sortBy('created_at')">Date</data-table-heading>
</template>
```

Data Table Heading Vue Component - Template

```
<span class="relative flex items-center">
    <div v-if="direction === 'asc'">
        <svg class="w-3 h-3" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="direction === 'desc'">
        <svg class="w-3 h-3" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M5 15l7-7 7 7"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <svg class="w-3 h-3 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-300" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M5 15l7-7 7 7"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
</span>
```

#### Edit

Livewire Component Sorting

```
public $sorts = [];

public function sortBy($field)
{
    if (! isset($this->sorts[$field])) return $this->sorts[$field] = 'asc';

    if ($this->sorts[$field] === 'asc') return $this->sorts[$field] = 'desc';

    unset($this->sorts[$field]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from the logic, is that there were problems in changing the state of `sortDirection`, it was because we were not resetting it to a normal state.

To change the `sortDirection` back to normal, use the below code:

```
sortBy: function(column) {
                if (column === this.sortField) {
                    this.sortDirection = this.sortDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : this.sortDirection == '' ? 'asc' : '';
                } else this.sortDirection = 'asc';
                this.sortField = column;
            }
```